# Error Creating First Pebble Project

Tags: pebble-watch

I am trying to create my first Pebble project and it simply fails when I run the pebble new_profile hello_world.

```
johndoe-mbp-2:projects johndoe$ pebble new-profile hello_world
[DEBUG   ] [Analytics] header: {'User-Agent': 'Pebble SDK/2.0-BETA6 (Darwin-13.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-python-2.7.5)'}, data: {'ck': '2.7.5', 'cn': 'Darwin-13.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit', 'cid': '3247db56-af31-4738-999a-uuuuu', 'tid': 'UA-66666-7', 't': 'event', 'v': 1, 'cs': '3247db56-af31-4738-999a-yyyyy'}
category: install
action: import
label: fail: missing import: No module named websocket
value: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johndoe/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA6/bin/../tools/pebble.py", line 14, in <module>
    import websocket        
ImportError: No module named websocket
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling any `websocket` module on your computer, and reinstalling the Pebble SDK depencies:

```
pip uninstall websocket
pip install --user -r ~/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA7/requirements.txt
```

Note: You will need to update the location of the SDK in this command line.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you provide an **absolute path** to the **requirements.txt** file. I tried running the command from the directory that I installed the Pebble SDK:

```
$PEBBLE_HOME> pip install requirements.txt
```

which resulted in:

```
Downloading/unpacking requirements.txt
  Real name of requirement requirements.txt is requirements.txt
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement requirements.txt
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for requirements.txt
Storing debug log for failure in $HOME/.pip/pip.log
```

Checking out that pip.log file showed that pip was trying to access requirements.txt from https://pypi.python.org/simple/requirements.txt/ which was 404ing.

Once I changed to use an absolute path it was all good:

```
> pip install -r $PEBBLE_HOME/requirements.txt # Where $PEBBLE_HOME is where you put the SDK
```